# How can I have C# code run after a jquery script that is running on page load?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that loads and runs jquery once the page is ready, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError);

        function showPosition(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById('div_latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
            document.getElementById('div_longitude').innerHTML = longitude;
        }

        function positionError(position) {
            alert("Error: " + position.code);
        }
    });
```

After I have assigned the div_latitude and div_longitude their values, I want to run code that will use this information automatically.  How can I make sure this second piece of code will run after the jquery?

Comment: you could call a webmethod or make an ajax call from the javascript, but it sounds like to need to rethink your design.

Comment: Is there no way to get the geolocation information from the server-side instead?

Comment: If you want to run c# code you'll need to do an ajax call to server logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to make an AJAX call up to the server.

Comment: Well, you could just perform a full page postback if you really felt like it.  AJAX is probably the *best* option, even if not the only one.

Comment: OK, I'll look into that. Is there any way you could give me an example of how it would be correctly used in this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check status in jquery as "complete" and you can make an AJAX call to C# codes you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make an ajax call to communicate to the server side code so that you can pass the vales you needed after jQuery is loaded.

Code is as follows.
$(document).ready(function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError);

```
    function showPosition(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById('div_latitude').innerHTML = latitude;
        document.getElementById('div_longitude').innerHTML = longitude;
    }

    function positionError(position) {
        alert("Error: " + position.code);
    }
     makeAjaxCall();

});
  function makeAjaxCall()
   {
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(msg) {
          // Ajax Call Successfull.
           }
       });
    }
```